# Flutter how to execute when clicking back button

Tags: flutter, dart, navigation, back-button

I have a page that is called from bottom tab nav which executes a initState function, I then navigate to a page via button click that has details and actions to take, however when I click the back button to goto originating page, the initState does not run again, I have found out that because Flutter does not destroy the page when you put one on top, since the NAV is not on new page as its not in the menu, how do I make initState run again on clicking back button or is there another way to listen for that navigate from back button and run the code that needs to update data?

Any help would be great.

Comment: You do not want to call initState again, it is easier to just change the state depending on Navigator.pop

Comment: How do I do that, this is the back button in the appBar, is there a way to affect that with a pop?

Comment: Check my answer down below

Comment: @Robert see this link, i have answered this question on how to call initState or update data when back button on navigation bar was pressed https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51927885/flutter-back-button-with-return-data

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can override the default back arrow on the `AppBar`and then specify the value you would like to return to trigger the change of the state when `Navigator.pop` is called:

**Pseudo-Code**

so you need to have something like this in your `onPressed` callback of your navigation button

```
onPressed: ()async{
            var nav = await Navigator.of(context).push(newRoute);
            if(nav==true||nav==null){
              //change the state
            }
          },
```

and in your newRoute you should have something like this

```
new AppBar(
        leading: new IconButton(
          icon: new Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
          onPressed: (){Navigator.pop(context,true)}
        ),
```

I am checking for both values `null` or `true` because the null value is returned when the user hits the BackButton on android screen (the one in the bottom of the screen). I also believe the null will also be returned with the default BackButton in Flutter so you do not actually need to override the `leading` property, but I have not checked that myself, so it may be worth checking.

Comment: So the first onPressed is that on the first page? and then override the leading on the resultant page?

Comment: exactly, nav value will resolve when you navigate back to this first page and that is how you link between push and returned value from pop

Comment: What if back button from device?

Comment: @stuckedoverflow try to use WillPopScope - see example below

Answer (score 44):

You can listen to the pop with [WillPopScope](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/WillPopScope-class.html) (Creates a widget that registers a callback to veto attempts by the user to dismiss the enclosing [ModalRoute]. -> from documentation):

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return WillPopScope(
  onWillPop: () {
    print('Backbutton pressed (device or appbar button), do whatever you want.');

    //trigger leaving and use own data
    Navigator.pop(context, false);

    //we need to return a future
    return Future.value(false);
  },
  child: Scaffold(
  ...
  ),
 );
}
```

Hopefully I got your question right and that helps :)!

Comment: Thanks! This is usually the way to go, since you would usually want to intercept the "popping", not just the back button of the AppBar. By the way, I just discovered a strange behaviour of WillPopScope in iOS, since it disables swipe back. See: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/14203.

Answer (score 2):

```
//if you want to perform  any operation on back button so you can use WillPopScope Widget and managed your code inside onWillpop method 

   
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return WillPopScope( 

        child:Column()),

        onWillPop: onBackPress);
   }
        
   
// this is onBackPress method
 Future<bool> onBackPress() {
        // your code 
   return Future.value(false);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, just invoking **whenComplete()** is enough. Take a look of the example :

```
Navigator.push(context,
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const YourRoute()))
    .whenComplete(() {
  // Do something when back to previous state
});
```