# Is there a way to have Navigator.of to run a function whenever something's popped?

Tags: flutter

My app depends (at least partially) on outside state (from the filesystem or settings). It's not that the user will update state on his own, it's just that when the app sets certain variable, it saves them to disk and when it's loaded, it reads them from disk.

As long as I don't navigate, everything works well (meaning that when I set state it is saved and when I restart the app the variables get restored). The problem is navigation - If I navigate a few screens in, change state, and then `pop` back a few screens, and state won't update.

This is expected, as popping should return the screen back to where it was before.

But the problem is that unless I manually restore settings at every `setState`, that variable isn't ever updated.

Is there a way to have `pop` run a function (or method) to update certain variables on pop?

If I don't pop it's not a problem, as when I change state on the filesystem I c

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48582963/flutter-how-to-execute-when-clicking-back-button/48597815#48597815

Comment: @aziza _almost_. But there it (um. You :) ) answer about intercepting a click on the back button on the AppBar. What about the back button on the phone?

Comment: this is already included in the answer (nav==true||nav==null), does not this work for you ?

Comment: check this too 
http://cogitas.net/know-user-tapped-back-button-back-navigation-arrow-flutter/