# Flutter Back button with return data

Tags: flutter, dart, back-button

I have an interface with two buttons that pop and return true or false, like so:

```
onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context, false)
```

I need to adapt the back button in the appbar, so it pops and also returns false. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This may help and work for you

**1st screen**

```
void goToSecondScreen()async {
 var result = await Navigator.push(_context, new MaterialPageRoute(
 builder: (BuildContext context) => new SecondScreen(context),
 fullscreenDialog: true,)
);

Scaffold.of(_context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text("$result"),duration: Duration(seconds: 3),));
}
```

**2nd screen**

```
Navigator.pop(context, "Hello world");
```

Comment: I don't think this answer covers the specifics of handling the back button.

Comment: i have try it. but, it didn't work when use onwillpop without navigator

Answer (score 79):

The easier way is to wrap the body in **WillPopScope**, in this way it will work with the **Back Button on the Top** AND the **Android Back Button on the Bottom**.

Here an example where both back buttons return false:

```
final return = Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute<bool>(
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("New Page"),
        ),
        body: WillPopScope(
          onWillPop: () async {
             Navigator.pop(context, false);
             return false;
          },
          child: newPageStuff(),
        ),
      );
    },
));
```

---

In the other answers they suggested to use:

> leading: BackButton(...)

I found that this works on with the Back Button on the Top and not with the Android one.

I include anyway an example:

```
final return = Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute<bool>(
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          leading: BackButton(
            onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context, false),
          ),
          title: Text("New Page"),
        ),
        body: newPageStuff(),
      );
    },
));
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it really helped me! But I suggest a little improvement in your first solution: the function that you pass as `onWillPop` parameter could be an `async` function, so that at the end of the block you can just `return false`.

Comment: In the docs for `onWillPop` it says "If the callback returns a Future that resolves to false, the enclosing route will not be popped".  So should the async callback itself return true?

Comment: @chanban the `async` function is handling the `true` return. `onWillPop` will return `false` on runtime.

Comment: For me, I am sending back a boolean true from second screen, but I am getting null value on first screen. Any idea on this ?

Comment: @raphire have you try `var value= await Navigator.pushName(context, '\second-screen')` at first screen ?

Comment: This answer could use an update using `PopScope` now that `WillPopScope` is deprecated.

Comment: Also note that `PopScope` and `WillPopScope` prevent the swipe back gesture on iOS from working. I eventually came to the conclusion that `PopScope` and `WillPopScope` are basically unusable unless you're trying to veto back navigation entirely.

Answer (score 39):

The default `BackButton` takes over the leading property of your `AppBar` so all you need to do is to override the `leading` property with your custom back button, for example:

```
leading: IconButton(
  icon: Icon(Icons.chevron_left),
  onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context, false),
),
```

Comment: Good answer!! This helped me a lot. However, we should use BackButtonIcon() in place of the Chevron to ensure sizing is correct. See Documentation: https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/BackButton-class.html and https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/BackButtonIcon-class.html

Comment: Android has a back button built into the OS.  iOS allows navigating back by swiping right.  A custom button in the Scaffold's `leading` property will not handle these other ways of navigating back.

Comment: This will catch back click on the AppBar, but it won't catch back if user pressed system back button at the bottom of the Android phone.

Comment: Shorter: `leading: BackButton(onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context, false),),`

Answer (score 13):

To pop the data and pass data back on navigation, you need to use `.then()` from screen 1. Below is the example.

Screen 2:

```
class DetailsClassWhichYouWantToPop {
  final String date;
  final String amount;
  DetailsClassWhichYouWantToPop(this.date, this.amount);
}

void getDataAndPop() {
      DetailsClassWhichYouWantToPop detailsClass = new DetailsClassWhichYouWantToPop(dateController.text, amountController.text);
      Navigator.pop(context, detailsClass); //pop happens here
  }

new RaisedButton(
    child: new Text("Edit"),
    color:  UIData.col_button_orange,
    textColor: Colors.white,
    onPressed: getDataAndPop, //calling pop here
  ),
```

Screen 1:

```
    class Screen1 extends StatefulWidget {
          //var objectFromEditBill;
          DetailsClassWhichYouWantToPop detailsClass;

          MyBills({Key key, this.detailsClass}) : super(key: key);

          @override
          Screen1State createState() => new Screen1State();
        }

        class Screen1State extends State<Screen1> with TickerProviderStateMixin {


        void getDataFromEdit(DetailsClassWhichYouWantToPop detailClass) {
        print("natureOfExpense Value:::::: " + detailClass.date);
        print("receiptNumber value::::::: " + detailClass.amount);
      }

      void getDataFromEdit(DetailsClassWhichYouWantToPop detailClass) {
        print("natureOfExpense Value:::::: " + detailClass.natureOfExpense);
        print("receiptNumber value::::::: " + detailClass.receiptNumber);
      }

      void pushFilePath(File file) async {
        await Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => Screen2(fileObj: file),
          ),
        ).then((val){
          getDataFromScreen2(val); //you get details from screen2 here
        });
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 7):

The simplest way to achieve this is to :

In your body take a `WillPopScope` as the parent widget
And on its `onWillPop : () {}` call

```
Navigator.pop(context, false);
```

`onWillPop` of `WillPopScope` will be triggered automatically when you’ll press the back button on your AppBar

Comment: *onWillPop: (){}

Answer (score 5):

While you can override the back button for custom behaviors, don't.

Instead of overriding the button with a custom pop, you should handle the null scenario.
There are a few reasons why you don't want to manually override the icon:

- The icon change on IOS and Android. On IOS it uses `arrow_back_ios` while android uses `arrow_back`
- The icon may automatically disappear if there's no route to go back
- Physical back button will still return `null`.

Instead should do the following:

```
var result = await Navigator.pushNamed<bool>(context, "/");
if (result == null) {
  result = false;
}
```

Comment: How do you return data from the page without calling `Navigator.pop` since the user might have pressed the hardware back button?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
void _onBackPressed() {
  // Called when the user either presses the back arrow in the AppBar or
  // the dedicated back button.
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return WillPopScope(
    onWillPop: () {
      _onBackPressed();
      return Future.value(false);
    },
    child: Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
          onPressed: _onBackPressed,
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: This worked for me on Chrome and Chrome for Android. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Use the below code to get result from your activity.

```
Future _startActivity() async {

Map results = await Navigator.of(context).push(new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context){
  return new StartActivityForResult();
}));

if (results != null && results.containsKey('item')) {
  setState(() {
    stringFromActivity = results['item'];
    print(stringFromActivity);
  });
}
}
```

Complete Source Code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'activity_for_result.dart';
import 'dart:async';
void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return new MaterialApp(
   title: 'Flutter Demo',
   theme: new ThemeData(
    primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
  ),
     home: new MyHomePage(title: 'Start Activity For Result'),
  );
 }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
 MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
 final String title;

 @override
 _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
 String stringFromActivity = 'Start Activity To Change Me \n';
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return new Scaffold(
  appBar: new AppBar(
    title: new Text(widget.title),
  ),
  body: new Center(
    child: new Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        new Text(
          stringFromActivity, style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0), textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        ),
        new Container(height: 20.0,),
        new RaisedButton(child: new Text('Start Activity'),
          onPressed: () => _startActivity(),)
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
}

Future _startActivity() async {

Map results = await Navigator.of(context).push(new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context){
  return new StartActivityForResult();
}));

if (results != null && results.containsKey('item')) {
  setState(() {
    stringFromActivity = results['item'];
    print(stringFromActivity);
  });
 }
 }
}

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class StartActivityForResult extends StatelessWidget{

 List<String>list = ['','','','','','','','','',];

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
// TODO: implement build

  return new Scaffold(
    appBar: new AppBar(
    title: new Text('Selecte Smily'),
  ),
  body: new ListView.builder(itemBuilder: (context, i){
    return new ListTile(title: new Text(list[i]),
      onTap: (){
        Navigator.of(context).pop({'item': list[i]});
      },
    );
  }, itemCount: list.length,),
  );
 }
}
```

get complete running example of how to work this from
[here](https://github.com/zmqgithub/startActivityforResult)

Answer (score 1):

You can pass data/arguments from one screen to other,

consider this example:

screen1.dart:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'screen2.dart';

class Screen1 extends StatelessWidget {
  Screen1(this.indx);

  final int indx;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new S1(indx: indx,);
  }
}

class S1 extends StatefulWidget {
  S1({Key key, this.indx}) : super(key: key);

  final int indx;

  @override
  S1State createState() => new S1State(indx);
}

class S1State extends State<VD> {

    int indx = 5;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        leading: new IconButton(icon: const Icon(Icons.iconName), onPressed: () {
          Navigator.pushReplacement(context, new MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (BuildContext context) => new Screen2(indx),
         ));
        }),
    ),
  );
 }
}
```

Screen 2:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'screen2.dart';

class Screen2 extends StatelessWidget {
 Screen2(this.indx);

 final int indx;

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
       return new S2(indx: indx,);
    }
 }

 class S2 extends StatefulWidget {
  S2({Key key, this.indx}) : super(key: key);

  final int indx;

  @override
  S2State createState() => new S2State(indx);
  }

 class S2State extends State<VD> {

 int indx = 1;

  @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
       return new Scaffold(
          appBar: new AppBar(
            leading: new IconButton(icon: const Icon(Icons.Icons.arrow_back), onPressed: () {
              Navigator.pushReplacement(context, new MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (BuildContext context) => new Screen1(indx),
             ));
            }),
        ),
      );
     }
    }
```

To pass data between Screens, pass the argument/data to the Screens constructor in `Navigator.pushReplacement()`.You can pass as many argument as you want.

This line

```
Navigator.pushReplacement(context, new MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (BuildContext context) => new Screen1(indx),
                 ));
```

will go to Screen1 and call initState and build method of Screen1 so that you can get updated values.

Answer (score 0):

First, Remove the automatically appended back button (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44978216/flutter-remove-back-button-on-appbar))

Then, create your own back button. like this:

```
IconButton(
    onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context, false),
    icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
    )
```