# Flutter - Pass Data Back with .popUntil

Tags: flutter, dart, navigator

I have been using `Navigator.pop` and passing data back 1 screen with ease. However, if I use `Navigator.popUntil`, what is an acceptable way to pass an object back to the destination screen?

Comment: I have already answer the question this may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51927885/flutter-back-button-with-return-data/51928001#51928001

Comment: @Zulfiqar It looks you are sending data to one level back. But the requirement is pass multiple level back

Comment: How many screens do you want to go back? How big(or what kind of) the data you want to pass? Don't have a `generic` answer, thinking for some workaround based on the answers to the above questions.

Comment: see if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/a/54455666/2033377

Answer (score 27):

You can using `arguments` in `RouteSettings` to pass data back to a specific `Route`.

For example:

```dart
// in MaterialApp
MaterialApp(
   onGenerateRoute: (settings) {
      switch (settings.name) {
         case '/':
            return MaterialPageRoute(
                     settings: RouteSettings(name: '/', arguments: Map()),  // (1)
                     builder: (_) => HomePage()
                  );
      }
   }
)

// in HomePage
Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => StuffPage())
                     .then(_) {
                        final arguments = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments as Map;
                        final result = arguments['result'];
                     };

// in StuffPage
Navigator.of(context).popUntil((route) {
   if (route.settings.name == '/') {
      (route.settings.arguments as Map)['result'] = 'something';
      return true;
   } else {
      return false;
   }
});
```

Note that: you have to initialize `arguments` or it will be null, that's what is the purpose of (1)

Comment: This must be an accepted answer. It will work in each condition i think. Well done @hunghd

Comment: `RouteSettings(name: '/', arguments: Map())` this one is the most important line of code

Comment: I need to clear the arguments once I have popped back. Any way to do that ?

Comment: When it says `popUntil` it will go till one step ahead of defined screen.
I am getting value as null

`.then((value) {
      print(value);
    });`

Comment: Does not work for single-shot behaviour. A map should be cleared after consuming the `result ` argument with: `(ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as Map).clear()`

Comment: showing error in this `  (route.settings.arguments as Map)['result'] = 'something';`    line`List<Object?>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<dynamic, dynamic>' in type cast`

Answer (score 2):

There is none. It also doesn't make sense because the result should be given back to the route that pushed the route.

If you really have to do this, use multiple `pop` calls:

```
// Widget of Route A:
String resultOfC = await Navigator.push(context, routeB);


// Widget of Route B:
String resultOfC = await Navigator.push<String>(context, routeC);
Navigator.pop(context, resultOfC); // pass result of C to A


// Widget of Route C:
Navigator.pop(context, 'my result'); // pass result to B
```

Comment: this will get displayed in view while the `popUntil` will not. So it would be better if we able to popUntil and pass the data also.

Comment: Yeah, there are other ways. I would like to know what OP is trying to do. It's probably a conceptual issue how he is using the `Navigator`.

Comment: This appears to be the most clean approach even though it causes tight coupling. I don't think the coupling is an issue though as it's two layers deep and probably won't occur often in most apps. If you have to go three layers back, I'd question this approach as too unwieldy.

Answer (score 0):

plus @hunghd [answer's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56218929/4862911) make sure that the `screen settings` that you will popback **must not have a** `const` key. otherwise you will be faced following error:

```
Unhandled Exception: Unsupported operation: Cannot modify unmodifiable map
```

I just removed the `const` key from settings on following code where the user will be popped back.

```
 case HomeViewRoute:
      return MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => HomePage(),
        settings: RouteSettings(name: HomeViewRoute, arguments:  {}),
      );
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution for **single shot argument reading**. As the solution proposed by @hunghd does not take this into account. The trick here is to consume arguments **once**, not many times as it might lead to wrong behaviours.

If we want to "go back with single result" we should do the following thing. We can draft the following **engine in three steps**:

**First step - setup in the Main.app:**

```dart
MaterialApp(
   onGenerateRoute: (settings) {
       switch (settings.name) {
           case Routes.HOME: // Or your other path, like "/"
               return generateRouteWithMapArguments(
                   Routes.HOME,
                   HomePage(), // A page Widget
               );
       // Other switch cases
      }
   }
)

// util:
static MaterialPageRoute generateRouteWithMapArguments(
    String routeName,
    Widget page,
  ) =>
      MaterialPageRoute(
        settings: RouteSettings(name: routeName, arguments: Map()),
        builder: (context) => page,
      );
```

**Second step - Performing navigation:**

```dart
const String ARGUMENTS_REMOVED = "ARGUMENTS_REMOVED";


void _navigateToDetails(BuildContext context) async {
    // navigate here help with the help of Navigator.of(context).push() or GetX
    await Navigator.of(context).push(...)
    var result = ArgsUtils.consumeArgument(
      context,
      ARGUMENTS_REMOVED,
      () {
        // HANDLE SINGLE SHOT HERE
      },
    );
  }

// utils:
class ArgsUtils {
  static T readArgs<T>(BuildContext context) {
    return ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as T;
  }

  static bool consumeArgument(
    BuildContext context,
    String argument,
    VoidCallback onArgument,
  ) {
    var map = readArgs<Map>(context);
    if (map.containsKey(argument)) {
      onArgument.call();
      map.clear();
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

***Third step - passing arguments back:**

```dart
// passing back. Call this method two pages after navigating deeper from HOME 
NavigatorUtils.popTwoPagesWithArgument(
    context,
    routeName: Routes.HOME,
    argument: ARGUMENTS_REMOVED,
);


// util:
class NavigatorUtils {
  // you can pop more pages here or add different predicate:
  static void popTwoPagesWithArgument(
    final BuildContext context, {
    required final String routeName,
    required final String argument,
  }) {
    int count = 0;
    Navigator.of(context).popUntil((route) {
      if (route.settings.name == routeName &&
          route.settings.arguments != null) {
        (route.settings.arguments! as Map)[argument] = true;
      }
      return count++ >= 2;
    });
  }
}
```

Of course this solution passes redundant `bool`. And this raises questions whether a `Map` is needed. For single-shot cases I believe that this can be improved by using `Set<String>` instead of `Map`.

Answer (score 0):

if you are working with a named Route then here is a fully working answer (Flutter3.16)

1. pass empty MAP "{}" as an argument while navigating to the main or first page (in my case it will be UserList

   ```
   Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(RouteConst.kUserList,arguments: {}),
   ```
2. Now 2 more screens will be pushed before the final User creates a screen (example)
3. and finally from the User Create screen I user popUntil with this code where I will return the full name of the user.

   ```
   Navigator.of(context).popUntil((route) {
      if (route.settings.name == RouteConst.kUserList) {
        (route.settings.arguments as Map)['name'] = "Full Name";
        return true;
      } 
      else {
        return false;
      }
   });
   ```

Properly working code let me know if you still stuck some where.

Answer (score -2):

For workaround solution until the Flutter team provides it, you can do it using shared_preferences.

1. Add class with function to get and save value to shared_preferences.

```dart
  static const isBackFromPopUntil = "isBackFromPopUntil";

  Future<void> saveIsBackFromPopUntil(bool isBack) async =>
      await preferences.setBool(isBackFromPopUntil, isBack);

  bool getIsBackFromPopUntil() =>
      preferences.getBool(isBackFromPopUntil) ?? false;
```

2. For example you need to check "someting" when modal bottom sheet is closed from `popUntil`, otherwise not.

```dart
  void _openBottomSheet(BuildContext context) async {
    await showCupertinoModalBottomSheet(
      context: context,
      isDismissible: true,
      ...
    );
    final isBack = _prefHelper.getIsBackFromPopUntil();
    if (isBack) {
      // do stuff
      await _prefHelper.saveIsBackFromPopUntil(false);
    }
  }
```

3. You back from the screen but using `popUntil`.

```dart
void _popUntilDetailSavingPlan(BuildContext context) async {
    final routeName = 'your name route that have bottom sheet (in the number 2 above)';
    await _prefHelper.saveIsBackFromPopUntil(true);
    Navigator.popUntil(context, ModalRoute.withName(routeName));
  }
```

Comment: this is a very bad approach to solve the problem