# How to return multiple arguments when popUntil？

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

```
Navigator.popUntil(context, (route) => route.isFirst);
```

I try this back transition this.
I wanna get bool argument at the same time.

```
class Position {
  Position(bool isFirst, bool value);
}

Navigator.popUntil(context, ((route) {
  return Position(route.isFirst, true);
}));
```

I tried this, but I got error.

```
The return type 'Position' isn't a 'bool', as required by the closure's context.
```

How can I do？

Answer (score 0):

Please do check the argument in position constructor.
I could see two data type mentioned in the place of variable name.

```
class Position {
  Position(bool isFirst, bool bool);
}
```

Change the above one to like below:

```
class Position {
  Position(bool isFirst, bool value1);
}
```

Comment: sorry name mistaking.But I got error. Please check error message in my question

Answer (score 0):

Please follow this link : [Flutter - Pass Data Back with .popUntil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52075130/flutter-pass-data-back-with-popuntil)

it should be boolean value.
for values you can write :

```
Navigator.popUntil(context, ((route) {
 (route.settings.arguments as Map)['result'] = 'data';
   return true;
}));
```

Comment: I got "type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Map<dynamic> in type cast"

Comment: you can do like this also  (route.settings.arguments )['result'] = 'data';