# How do i pass more than one values using Navigator.pop() method in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

`Navigator.pop` method can return only one value but I need to return multiple values. 
Is there any way to return multiple values using `Navigator.pop()`?

I've previously used `Navigator.push` but when I push multiple variables from many pages to one page it shows construction error.

I'have been stuck here for days.

Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you want to return multiple values using ```Navigator.pop()```? What logic are you trying to enact?

Comment: i just want to get data from different page to home where i use those data as input to api. i want to do what momondo app does form flight search.

Answer (score 6):

You can `pop` in two ways:

```
Navigator.of(context).pop(object);
```

or

```
Navigator.pop(context, object);
```

Either way, I've flagged with `object` the **optional** return value for the method.

If you desire to return more than one values, you'll need to box them in an object, `class` or `Map` or whatever.

Boxing with a class will look like this:

```
class BoxedReturns{
    final int a;
    final int b;

    BoxedReturns(this.a, this.b);
}

//stuff
Navigator.of(context).pop(BoxedReturns(1,2));
```

You can do something similar by using a map, although I'd rather use the class approach:

```
Navigator.of(context).pop({"a":1,"b":2});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Map

```
final data = { "key1" : "value1", "key2" : "value2" };
Navigator.of(context).pop(data);
```

Answer (score 1):

To be able to return multiple values via `Navigator.pop()` you could do 2 things (surely even more ways but those are some basic ones):

**1. Creating a model holding those data:**

```dart
class YourClass {
  String firstVar;
  String secondVar;
  int thirdVar;

  News(
      {this.firstVar,
      this.secondVar,
      this.thirdVar});
}
```

Inside your view where you want to return data with `Navigator.pop()`:

```dart
...
Navigator.pop(context, YourClass('test', 'test2', '1'));
```

**2. Using a `Map` to hold nested (in my case tupels):**

```dart
...
Map<String, int> myData = new Map();
myData['test'] = 1;
myData['test2'] = 2;
Navigator.pop(context, myData);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a new data structure class containing all data.
You can also use map or list, but it will be a possible bug source if data structure changes.

Answer (score 0):

Similar question [Flutter Back button with return data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51927885/flutter-back-button-with-return-data). 
 
code snippet from Deepak Thakur

```
class DetailsClassWhichYouWantToPop {
  final String date;
  final String amount;
  DetailsClassWhichYouWantToPop(this.date, this.amount);
}

void getDataAndPop() {
      DetailsClassWhichYouWantToPop detailsClass = new DetailsClassWhichYouWantToPop(dateController.text, amountController.text);
      Navigator.pop(context, detailsClass); //pop happens here
  }

new RaisedButton(
    child: new Text("Edit"),
    color:  UIData.col_button_orange,
    textColor: Colors.white,
    onPressed: getDataAndPop, //calling pop here
  ),
```

Comment: How do we access the result value? I get error like `Error: The getter 'amount' isn't defined for the class 'Object'.` and the program doesn't compile.

Comment: @skadoosh, Need to reproduce your question. could you put reproduce code to a new question and ping my name. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Simple Example:**

[image]

*You can send your custom object via **result** parameter.*

**Push to and get result from new Screen:**
Navigate to new-screen wait for *then()* or *complete()* event to happen.

```
pushToNewScreen() {
  Navigator.push(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => NewScreen()),
  ).then((value) {
    // if value is true you get the result as bool else no result 
    if (value != null && value == true) {
      print('Do something after getting result');
    } else {
      print('Do nothing');
    }
  });
}
```

**Get Data from new Screen when some event happens**

```
ontap: (){
    // pass your custom object inlace of bool value
    Navigator.pop(context, true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting from Dart 3.0, you can use [`Record`](https://dart.dev/language/records).

```dart
Navigator.of(context).pop((firstValue, secondValue));
```