# Flutter How can I pass more than 2 values to another screen on ListView?

Tags: flutter, flutter-listview

I am making a bookmark app that you can add title and URL from a dialog and listed on the screen.
I am trying to pass values from 2 textfields on Dialog to ListView on the last screen but I could not make it. On the dialog, there are 2 textfields (Title and URL) and I would like to pass these texts to ListView on last screen. I'v tried to use `pop` method but it doesn't work. Could anyone help me please?
Here is the whole codes.

**main.dart**

```
void main() {
  runApp(const BookmarkApp());
}

class BookmarkApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const BookmarkApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Bookmark App',
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.blue),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home:  BookmarkListPage(text: '', url: '',),
    );
  }
}

class BookmarkListPage extends StatefulWidget {
  BookmarkListPage({super.key, title, required this.text, required this.url});

  String text;
  String url;

  final String title = 'Bookmark List';

  @override
  State<BookmarkListPage> createState() => _BookmarkListPageState();
}

class _BookmarkListPageState extends State<BookmarkListPage> {

  List<String> bookmarkList = [];
  List<String> bookmarkUrl = [];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        title: Text(widget.title),
        bottom: PreferredSize(
          child: Container(
            height: 1,
            color: Colors.black,
          ),
          preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(1),
        ),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: bookmarkList.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Card(
            child: ListTile(
              title: Text(bookmarkList[index]),
              subtitle: Text(bookmarkUrl[index]),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),

      // show dialog to add a bookmark
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        shape: const CircleBorder(),
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
        onPressed: () async {
          final newBookmarkList = await showDialog(
              context: context,
              builder: (_) {
                return BookmarkDialog();
              });

          if (newBookmarkList != null) {
            setState(() {
              bookmarkList.add(newBookmarkList);
              bookmarkUrl.add(newBookmarkList);
            });
          }
        },
        child: const Icon(
          Icons.add,
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}
```

**dialog.dart**

```
class BookmarkDialog extends StatefulWidget {
  const BookmarkDialog({super.key});

  @override
  BookMarkDialogState createState() => BookMarkDialogState();
}

class BookMarkDialogState extends State<BookmarkDialog> {
  String bookmarkTitle = "";
  String bookmarkUrl = "";

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AlertDialog(
      title: const Text('Add Bookmark'),
      content: Column(
        children: [
          Text('Title'),
          TextField(onChanged: (value) {
            setState(() {
              bookmarkTitle = value;
            });
          }),
          Text('URL'),
          TextField(
            onChanged: (value) {
              setState(() {
                bookmarkUrl = value;
              });
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
      actions: <Widget>[
        GestureDetector(
          child: const Text('Cancel'),
          onTap: () {
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
        ),
        GestureDetector(
          child: const Text('Add'),
          onTap: () {
            Navigator.of(context).pop(bookmarkTitle);
          },
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do i pass more than one values using Navigator.pop() method in flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57370739/how-do-i-pass-more-than-one-values-using-navigator-pop-method-in-flutter)

Comment: I see the text that I input on title for both title and url on the ListView. 
ex: You see 'Google' on title and 'subtitle' even though you input 'Google' for title and 'https....' for url.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using Dart version of at least 3.0, you can use [Record](https://dart.dev/language/records).

```dart
Navigator.of(context).pop((bookmarkTitle, bookmarkUrl));
```

You can then read the values by using [pattern variable declaration](https://dart.dev/language/patterns#variable-declaration):

```dart
final (newBookmarkTitle, newBookmarkUrl) = await showDialog(
  context: context,
  builder: (_) {
    return BookmarkDialog();
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. but I can see only title from textfield not both title and url. How can I show bothe title and url on ListView? 
Maybe, around this code.

body: ListView.builder

Comment: I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you for your additonal answer. I solved the problem I had! Thank you so much!!