# How to Passing Data from Navigator Pop to Previous Page Where The Data is Used in The Widget Inside the ListView.builder

Tags: flutter

As stated in the title. How to return data to the previous page where the data is used to list widgets.

I have read this article [Flutter Back button with return data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51927885/flutter-back-button-with-return-data) or other similar articles. The code works perfectly. But there is a problem if I want to use the data returned to the widget that is in the list.\

Note that I only want to update one ListWidget, I don't want to refresh the state of the entire HomePage like the solution in this article [Flutter: Refresh on Navigator pop or go back](https://www.nstack.in/blog/flutter-refresh-on-navigator-pop-or-go-back/).

Here is a simple code sample to represent the problem I'm facing.

(check on ListWidget Class and SecondPage Class below)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}
```

HomePage class

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Home'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: 4,
          itemBuilder: (_, index){
            return ListWidget(number: index+1);
          },
        )
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

ListWidget Class

```
class ListWidget extends StatelessWidget{
  ListWidget({@required this.number});
  
  final int? number;
  String? statusOpen;
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () async {
        statusOpen = await Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true)
                .push(
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (BuildContext context) => SecondPage(),
                  ),
                );
      },
      child: Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
        color: Colors.amber,
        child: Text(statusOpen != null ? '$number $statusOpen' : '$number Unopened'),
        // 
        // I want to change the text here to 'has Opened' when the user returns from SecondPage
        //
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

SecondPage Class

```
class SecondPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Second Page'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pop(context, 'has Opened');
            // return 'has Opened' to await statusOpen variable
          },
          child: Text('Go Back'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

is there any solution to handle this?

Answer (score 1):

If you make your `listWidget` a stateful widget, then you can get the solution where you just need to call `setState` when you return to your previous screen. And in this way you will be only changing your single list element and not the full screen.

sample code:
changing this line- `class ListWidget extends StatefulWidget`
and adding these lines -

```
      onTap: () async {
        statusOpen = await Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true)
                .push(
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (BuildContext context) => SecondPage(),
                  ),
                );
        setState(() {
      
        });
      },
```

Answer (score 0):

If you used the data in your listview just call setstate after Navigator.pop like below code

```
 onTap: () async {
            statusOpen = await Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true)
                    .push(
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (BuildContext context) => SecondPage(),
                      ),
                    ).then((value) async {
              setState(() {});
           
            });
          },
```