# How to set a pop up message to appear in a page when Navigating from a specific route in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-design, dart-ui

I am wondering If there is a way to set a pop up message (Alert Dialogs) to appear on the screen when coming from a specific page.
Lets say that I have 3 screens. When I navigate from screen 1 to screen 2, no pop message will appear, however if I navigate from screen 3 to screen 1, a pop up message will then appear.
Any ideas on how can I implement something like that.

Comment: Using Navigator.pop with result to tell the previous route to do things.

Comment: @dante Thanks for your response. Could you please provide some example

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51927885/flutter-back-button-with-return-data using var result = await Navigator.push()

Comment: Please include your code